# Closing stdout and scripts

Tags: c++, stdout

I have two processes written in C++, piped one after the other. One gives some information to the other's `stdin`, then they both go on to do something else.

The problem is that the second process hangs inside `cin.getline()`, even though there's no more data to be exchanged. The solution was for the first process to `fclose(stdout)`, and that works, except when I use the process wrapped up in a script. So apparently the `stdout` of the script is still open after closing it by the process - which seems fair but in my case, can I close it? Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to? You provide too little information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The point is that process B must iterate through stdin and then do something else. But since process A (the writer) never finishes, the input doesn't contain EOF so process B continues to wait for input, instead of moving on.

Answer (score 0):

Since your program doesn't terminate, you can `exec your-program` in the script instead of just `your-program` and save an open file descriptor at the writing end of the pipe (and a bunch of other things).

Alternatively, start your program in the background and exit the script.

You can also close the standard output, but if you do that before you start your program, it won't be able to use the closed file descriptor. So you have to close it *while* the program is running. This is not exactly trivial. I can think of starting the program in the background, closing the standard output (use `exec 1>&-` for that) and bringing the program back to the foreground.